# Connecting to GA4 google analytics data api and google client without composer using php

Tags: php, google-api

Hi i am trying to connect to google api so i can get my stats via the browser.   I dont want to use composer.   How can i do this?

I downloaded this

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: you are using the wrong client library

Comment: The only way to connect is via the api.  The php cloud library just makes it easer for you.  You could code it all yourself if you wanted to.

Comment: This api accesses private user data in order to access private user data you need consent from the owner of the data.    service accounts need to be authorized by the owner of the account you are trying to access this is done by adding it as a user in the admin section of google analytics website

Comment: Service accounts should only be used to access data you the developer own, you should not be requesting a user to grant you access with a service account.   You shouldnt need to tell your customers how to run your app assuming its hosted on a website just have them click a button.

Comment: feel free to contact me I have a consulting service and would be happy to go though your use case with you.   It may save you some time chasing your tail if you know what is actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong client library to start with you want the [googleapis/php-analytics-data](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data)

TBH I have never tried to install it without composer in theory you should be able to grab the [V1beta](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data/tree/master/src/V1beta) directory and just use that but I havent tried.

Comment: probably you should try it with composer locally to begin with then you can work on without composer

Comment: Its nice to hear that the cloud library can also be loaded without composer